# My system restarts after the shutdown i cant shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown, hp, amd-graphics

Hey i have recently updated my ubuntu system are it an HP laptop

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64 
Host: HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eh2xxx 
Kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic 
Uptime: 5 mins 
Packages: 2937 (dpkg), 1 (pkg), 7 (f 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 44.3 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon G 
GPU: AMD ATI 03:00.0 Barcelo 
Memory: 2407MiB / 7268MiB
```

after this update my system just restart instead of shutdown also i get these errors when booting up

```
Nov 02 10:31:16 hp-pavilion kernel: amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
Nov 02 10:31:16 hp-pavilion kernel: amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
Nov 02 10:31:16 hp-pavilion kernel: amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
Nov 02 10:31:16 hp-pavilion kernel: amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
Nov 02 10:31:16 hp-pavilion kernel: amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
Nov 02 10:31:16 hp-pavilion kernel: amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
Nov 02 10:31:16 hp-pavilion kernel: amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
```

i have uploaded my complete journalctl logs file here [journal-ctl-file-link](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/2865e500-5d04-47a4-8cb7-1c6fe476df7d)
i have tried tried these commands already but behaviour is same it just restarts instead of shutdown.

```
shutdown -h now
```

also i have tried

```
systemctl poweroff
```

i have also tried adding **acpi=off** in grub file this also didnt worked
i am using ubuntu standalone so i dont have fast-boot option in bios. i have tried to shutdown while completely disconnected from the internet.I dont have **laptop-mode-tools** installed.Any help will be appreciated as currently only method i have is to force poweroff my device by holding power key.My lspci info is below

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN550 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
admin-d@hp-pavilion
```

Comment: I just waited as i dont find any propper solution what i did to propperly shutdown my computer is use advance options when system boots and then selected old kernal version 6.2.0-35-generic and shutdown work perfectly fine with this version. and some upgrades from the update center i got kernal update 6.2.0-39-generic and it got fixed there now my system shutdown properly the problem persists on kernal version 6.2.0-36 and 37 but now works fine on  6.2.0-39-generic